# Pyspark - how to check which of the two records has the latest date and its column value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame and want to check that a record with the latest date has a certain value. For example, for the below DF I need to check the records with Id 'B30' and get the record with the `metric_1` == 0.25.

```
original_metrics_df = self.spark.createDataFrame(
    [('A10', -0.35, '2020-01-04'),
     ('A20', -0.20, '2017-05-01'),
     ('B30', 0.59, '2018-02-08'),
     ('B30', 0.25, '2019-05-01')
     ],
    ['id', 'metric_1', 'transaction_date']
)
```

First I did the filtering to retain only records with Id `B30`:

`filtered_metrics_df = original_metrics_df.select('id','metric_1').filter(F.col('metric_1') == 'B30')`

How should I apply filtering further to get only a `metric_1` value of this record `('B30', 0.25, '2019-05-01')`?

Comment: @anky there are no duplicates in transaction_date column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try on a window :

If the transaction_date is not a date column convert to date:

```
original_metrics_df = original_metrics_df.withColumn("transaction_date",
                                F.to_date("transaction_date"))
```

Then we can get max of date over a window and select the desired condition:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("id")
cond = (F.col("id")=="B30") & (F.col("transaction_date")==F.col("Latest_date"))

(original_metrics_df.withColumn("Latest_date",F.max("transaction_date").over(w))
 .filter(cond).drop("Latest_date")).show()
```

---

```
+---+--------+----------------+
| id|metric_1|transaction_date|
+---+--------+----------------+
|B30|    0.25|      2019-05-01|
+---+--------+----------------+
```

Or , filter on the known condition first and then do the same operation:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("id")

(original_metrics_df.filter(F.col("id")=="B30")
  .withColumn("Latest_date",F.max("transaction_date").over(w))
  .filter(F.col("transaction_date")==F.col("Latest_date"))).show()
```